# Grouping and Minifying Python Modules Using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I want to group and minimize the lines of code I have, just click on the arrow for that service:

[image]

[image]

And if I want to do the same thing by grouping and minimizing the list of modules that I import, is there anyway they don't take up so much space?

[image]

Comment: Not specific to Visual Studio, but you can theoretically list modules on a single line e.g. `import os, sys` rather than e.g. `import os` then `import sys` on separate lines. That said, the PEP-8 guidelines for importing modules recommend the single line format for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Prettier - Code formatter extension. Might be necessary to restart VS Code after installing the extension.
2. Open your python file.
3. Bring the cursor on the left of the first import statement. The arrow key to group/minify them will be shown. You can then group or minify.

[image: VS Code editor]

Comment: Hi mate, can you tell me if this option is linked to some extension need to install? Because here it doesn't show up for me in any of my files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrondbyIF I have Prettier - Code formatter extension installed, and it is allowing me to accomplish what you requested. I will update my answer.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much. I used Pylance, but with it deactivated, my code runs using 700mb more or less, with it activated the code adds memory expense, exceeding 3gb, I ended up deactivating it. I will use what you indicated, maybe I will get better results, thank you very much!